# Upload file into google drive folder using Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-drive-android-api

I want to create file inside a specific folder in google drive ( not the default location ) using Xamarin.Andriod

I'm using the below code

```
 MetadataChangeSet changeSetfile = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                   .SetTitle("Test.jpg")
                   .SetMimeType("image/jpeg")
                   .Build();

            DriveClass.DriveApi
                   .GetRootFolder(_googleApiClient)
                    .CreateFile(_googleApiClient, changeSetfile, contentResults.DriveContents);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Implement `GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks`
2. Obtain a `GoogleApiClient` with `DriveClass.API` and `DriveClass.ScopeFile`

#### `GoogleApiClient` Example:

```
if (_googleApiClient == null) //  _googleApiClient is a class level variable
{
    _googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
      .AddApi(DriveClass.API)
      .AddScope(DriveClass.ScopeFile)
      .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
      .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(onConnectionFailed)
      .Build();
}
if (!_googleApiClient.IsConnected)
    _googleApiClient.Connect();
```

3. Once connected, Query for folder, create if needed and then "write" a file to it.

#### Folder and File Example:

```
var folderName = "StackOverflow";
using (var driveId = DriveClass.DriveApi.GetRootFolder(_googleApiClient))
using (var query = new QueryClass.Builder().AddFilter(Filters.And(Filters.Eq(SearchableField.Title, folderName), Filters.Eq(SearchableField.Trashed, false))).Build())
using (var metaBufferResult = await driveId.QueryChildrenAsync(_googleApiClient, query))
{
    if (metaBufferResult.Status.IsSuccess)
    {
        DriveId folderId = null;
        foreach (var metaData in metaBufferResult.MetadataBuffer)
        {
            if (metaData.IsFolder && metaData.Title == folderName)
            {
                folderId = metaData.DriveId;
                break;
            }
        }

        IDriveFolder driveFolder = null;
        switch (folderId)
        {
            case null: // if folder not found, create it and fall through to default
                using (var folderChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().SetTitle(folderName).Build())
                using (var folderResult = await driveId.CreateFolderAsync(_googleApiClient, folderChangeSet))
                {
                    if (!folderResult.Status.IsSuccess)
                    {
                        Log.Error(TAG, folderResult.Status.StatusMessage);
                        break;
                    }
                    driveFolder = folderResult.DriveFolder;
                }
                goto default;
            default:
                driveFolder = driveFolder ?? folderId.AsDriveFolder();

                // create your file in the IDriveFolder obtained, 
                using (var contentResults = await DriveClass.DriveApi.NewDriveContentsAsync(_googleApiClient))
                {
                    if (contentResults.Status.IsSuccess)
                    {
                        using (var writer = new OutputStreamWriter(contentResults.DriveContents.OutputStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write("StackOverflow Rocks");
                            using (var changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .SetTitle("StackOverflow Rocks")
                                .SetStarred(true)
                                .SetMimeType("text/plain")
                                .Build())
                            using (var driveFileResult = await driveFolder.CreateFileAsync(_googleApiClient, changeSet, contentResults.DriveContents))
                            {
                                if (driveFileResult.Status.IsSuccess)
                                    Log.Debug(TAG, "File created, open https://drive.google.com to review it");
                                else
                                    Log.Error(TAG, driveFileResult.Status.StatusMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                driveFolder.Dispose();
                break;
        }
        folderId?.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Error(TAG, metaBufferResult.Status.StatusMessage);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- Do this on a background thread
- Drive allows multiple files/folders with same name (`Title`)

  - Query for existing files if you want to replace one
  - Query for existing folders unless you really what multiple folders with the same `Title`
- Folders and files in the `Trash` are returned queries unless excluded.
- Make use of `Using` blocks and `Dispose` to avoid leaks

Comment: If I already has folder ID , can I use this code folderId = DriveId.DecodeFromString("DriveId:1Q-eJcxoTjnZ_7wcAzKvb-WqBlbFyK04h");

Comment: @MedhatKhalifa `EncodeFromString` does not produce a stable ID, so do not hard-code or store that value as it can (and will) change and thus your `DecodeFromString` will fail to produce a valid DriveId. Always do a fresh query it get your DriveId. `ToInvariantString` on the DriveId instance will produce a stable ID but it is for equality checking, logging, etc.. and you can **not** use DecodeFromString on it.

Comment: ,okay but how can I add permission to make this created folder shared with other email address

Comment: @MedhatKhalifa This API does not expose access control list (ACL) for sharing, the REST api does, so you would need to login the user in via OAuth2 and use the access token to make the calls:  https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing