# upload image files using google drive Api

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Trying to upload an image file (already existing) from a user's phone (Android) on his google drive via my app using drive API and Xamarin (C#). There are several solutions to upload but they all are showing to upload a new file.. for example

[Google Drive API implementation Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432491/google-drive-api-implementation-xamarin-android)

[Upload file into google drive folder using Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619108/upload-file-into-google-drive-folder-using-xamarin-android)

both the solution given by @sushihangover create a new text file and then upload it via v3 API. I looked into the API as well but couldn't sort it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> upload image files using google drive Api

You could use the following codes to upload the image file to Google Drive :

```
DriveClass.DriveApi.NewDriveContents(client).SetResultCallback(new System.Action<IDriveApiDriveContentsResult>((result)=> {

            //Create MetadataChangeSet
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .SetTitle("Test.jpg")
                .SetMimeType("image/jpeg").Build();

            var contents = result.DriveContents;

            //push the bitmap data to DriveContents
            bitmapFromYourPicture.Compress(CompressFormat.Jpeg, 1, contents.OutputStream);
            IntentSender intentSender = DriveClass.DriveApi
                    .NewCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .SetInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .SetInitialDriveContents(contents)
                    .Build(client);

            StartIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, 2, null, 0, 0, 0);
        }));
```

If you choose the image picture by using intent you could get the picture `Bitmap` like this :

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        var uri = data.Data;

        System.IO.Stream image_stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap getBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(image_stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @York Shen. It worked but whenever I upload an image a new screen comes on Android to ask to rename/name the file being uploaded. Is there any way which just upload the file in the background? As I have to upload multiple images... Thanks again