# Store file with the storage access framework on Google Drive

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, storage-access-framework

I want to store a file with the Android storage access framework. My test code should store a file "hallo1" with the size of 1000000. But only a file "hallo1" with the filesize 0 will be created. I get no error message. The saving on local disc and sd-card works fine only google drive does not work.
The Code:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate
        {
            Intent intentCreate = new Intent(Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
            intentCreate.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            intentCreate.SetType("audio/*");
            intentCreate.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, "hallo" + count);
            StartActivityForResult(intentCreate, 1);

            count++;
        };
    }

    protected override  void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        var stream = this.ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(data.Data, "w");
        var b = new byte[1000000];
        stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();

        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

[Filepicker from the android storage access framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mUjZ.png)

[Enter the filename (default "hallo1" from the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/habiv.png)

data.Data gives an internal Android.Net.Uri back.

Somebody an idea where is the problem?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: c# with Mono.Android

Comment: You should add that as a tag

Comment: I see no Google Drive.

Comment: @greenapps  If you click on the button a filepicker opens and you can choose google drive or local storage files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
        protected override  void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        // this works fine:
        using (System.IO.Stream stream = this.ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(data.Data, "w"))
        {
            using (var javaStream = new Java.IO.BufferedOutputStream(stream))
            {
                var b = new byte[1000000];
                javaStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                javaStream.Flush();
                javaStream.Close();
            }
        }

        // the direct writing on the System.IO.Stream failed:
        //using (System.IO.Stream stream = this.ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(data.Data, "w"))
        //{
        //    var b = new byte[1000000];
        //    stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        //    stream.Flush();
        //    stream.Close();
        //}

        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Somebody a idea why this works and the direct writing with the System.IO.Stream failed?

Comment: I think there is something missing in the Android.Mono framework.

Answer (score 1):

> Store file with the storage access framework on Google Drive

Please refer to: [Google Drive API implementation Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432491/google-drive-api-implementation-xamarin-android)

Other useful links:

- [Upload image files using google drive Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268063/upload-image-files-using-google-drive-api/48295259#48295259)
- [Upload file into google drive folder using Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619108/upload-file-into-google-drive-folder-using-xamarin-android)
- [Xamarin forms upload to google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227086/xamarin-forms-upload-to-google-drive/39233810#39233810)

## Update:

> With internal storage it works and in my opinion it should also work with google drive.

**You can't directly implement this feature without using Google Drive API**, you should create your file first, then upload the file to Google Drive like this:

```
void IResultCallback.OnResult(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    var contentResults = (result).JavaCast<IDriveApiDriveContentsResult>();
    if (!contentResults.Status.IsSuccess) // handle the error
        return;
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var writer = new OutputStreamWriter(contentResults.DriveContents.OutputStream);
        writer.Write("Stack Overflow");
        writer.Close();
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
            .SetTitle("New Text File")
            .SetMimeType("text/plain")
            .Build();
        DriveClass.DriveApi
            .GetRootFolder(_googleApiClient)
            .CreateFile(_googleApiClient, changeSet, contentResults.DriveContents);
    });
}
```

For more detailed information, refer to the link I post above: [Google Drive API implementation Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432491/google-drive-api-implementation-xamarin-android).

---

Also, you could use the [Xamarin.Google.Drive.Api.Android](https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-xamarin-android-sdk) nuget package to implement this feature easily, simple demo from the [document](https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-xamarin-android-sdk#code-example):

```
CloudRail.AppKey = "{Your_License_Key}";
// Google Drive:
GoogleDrive drive = new GoogleDrive(this, "[clientIdentifier]", "", "[redirectUri]", "[state]");
drive.UseAdvancedAuthentication();
ICloudStorage cs = drive;

new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
{
    try
    {
        IList<CloudMetaData> filesFolders = cs.GetChildren("/");
        //IList<CloudMetaData> filesFolders = cs.GetChildrenPage("/", 1, 4);  // Path, Offet, Limit
        //cs.Upload(/image_2.jpg,stream,1024,true);   // Path and Filename, Stream (data), Size, overwrite (true/false)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
 })).Start();
```

## Update 2:

> To get the filename I found but not the folder name.

You need get `Cursor` from the `URI` first, then you can check column names etc.

For Google drive, there is a column name `_display_name`. This will give you the file name.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    var uri = data.Data;
    ICursor cursor = this.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.MoveToFirst();

    var filenameIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndex("_display_name");
    var filename = cursor.GetString(filenameIndex);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("filename == " + filename);
}
```

Comment: It should also work with the storage access framework. This whould be a good way to implement easy a filepicker. The result is data.Data, a Android.Net.Uri. It is a internal path. With internal storage it works and in my opinion it should also work with google drive.

Comment: @urs32, you still need to use the Google Drive API if you want to upload a file to Google Drive.

Comment: @YorgShen: If this would be the only way i can not use this framework at all to save files. Because if one function does not work i can not release it. The result uri is only internal  {content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D2%3Bdoc%3D148} ond i can not get a path form this. Only to get the filename and size i found a possibility.

Comment: @YorgShen: Thank you. But i have no idea how i can get the google drive folder from the encrypted uri (content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D2%3Bdoc%3D148). It should give mit "/testordner/hallo1". To get the filname i found but not the foldername.

Comment: @YorgShen: Yes, i now the code from your Update 2. But i need also the foldername, not only the filename.